# Internet connection yet cant browse

Tags: internet-explorer, dns, ip, vpn, router

ive got 2 computers connected to one router. everything worked nicely until some time ago i couldn't browse the internet anymore on one of the computers. the computer showed it was still connected to the internet yet i couldn't use browsers or any other software to actually browse it. i tried pinging some sites and i got a "ping request could not find host" error. i also tried switching the cables and the connections on the router, the problem doesn't change and it stays on the same computer. i tried deleting the anti virus and i checked the firewall, i tried ipconfig /renew and all the other similar cmd commands, it didnt work. 
the problem started about the first time i used a vpn software called "tunnel bear". i deleted the software since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "**Ping request could not find host**" error is related to DNS. Either the host name you entered is incorrect, something is wrong with your DNS servers, or you're not able to reach the Internet.

Test your basic connectivity:

- Ping your default gateway
- Ping 8.8.8.8

If the pings work then try to change the DNS server on one of your computers to 8.8.8.8 and see if you can browse again. If it works then the DNS server(s) given to your computers (by your router) isn't correct.